# Form Multi Select validation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have multi select and populating option value from data base.Default option value  will be 'Select Group' and next data will be group names which i have retrieve from db.I need to validate if default option is 'Select Group', i need to display alert 'Please select a Group'. How to validate this in rails?

```
        <select id="select-group-update" class="form-control" onClick="getParamListForCustomGroupUpdate()">
          <option value="" >Select Group Name</option>
            <%= options_from_collection_for_select(group.where(User_id: @user.id),:groupname,:groupname)%>

        </select>
```

Comment: `document.getElementById('select-group-update').value` should return selected option value...

Comment: yes.I tried with this

Comment: if ($('#select-group-update').val() === 'Select Group Name') {
        alert('Please Select Parameters!!!');
        return false;
    }

Comment: But didn't work

Comment: Value of `Select Group Name` is ""(Empty). You should be testing with `""`

Comment: Thanks.Now it is working.